# Radio Button for page Selection Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, alert

I'm Learning Please Help. I Appreciate any replys

I would like to to know how to make an alert message where it ask the user to select one page and once it selected load into that particular page.

for example i would like to have

Home page - index.html

About Us - about.html

Contact Us -contact.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changePage(pageNum) {
        if (pageNum == 1) { var pageURL = 'page1.html'; }
        if (pageNum == 2) { var pageURL = 'page2.html'; }
        if (pageNum == 3) { var pageURL = 'page3.html'; }
        window.location.href = pageURL;
    }
</script>

<h1>Select Page:</h1>
<input type="button" onclick="changePage(1);" value="Page 1">
<input type="button" onclick="changePage(2);" value="Page 2">
<input type="button" onclick="changePage(3);" value="Page 3">
```

Comment: Thank you, So Can you please tell me how to turn this function as "alert" so before home page loads, user see the alert and make selection.. thank you very much

Comment: To be honest, you'd be better off making a `landing page` with good ol' HTML, and using simple `<a>` links to allow navigation.  Otherwise, what you're looking for would be called a `lightbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use HTML links, no script necessary:

```
<a href="index.html">Home page</a>
```

Using any kind of popup for genearl navigation is just plain annoying.

To do what you are asking, learn how to create an element (say a div) with the links as content, then display or hide it depending on some user action. You may also want to position it in the page and have it cover other content, but they are just further annoyances.